# big-Oh prove or disprove 2^n is in big-Oh(3^n)

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

the definiton of Big-Oh says $\exists c\in$R+,$\exists B\in$ N,$\forall n\in$N, $n \geq B$$\implies$$2^n \leq c\times 3^n$. I believe $2^n \in O(3^n)$, but how to prove it? can anyone help.[image]

This this the proof I write. Is there any mistake there?

Comment: Yes, let $c=B=1$.

Comment: Simply choose $c=B=1$.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you may take $c=B=1$. A simpler proof would be to say that since $2^n<3^n$ for all $n>0$ we have by definition that $2^n\in O(3^n)$.